# Socket recv() function get null message

Tags: c, sockets

I have a problem about the recv() function.
When I sent the first message(ex: hi) to server first, the server would send back the same message to client.
And I sent again(ex: hi2), I would get a null message.
But I kept sending message,maybe I sent two times again. I got the second message I sent.

I want the result is client send to server and client receive the right message immediately.

How can I solve this problem?

my client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int sockFD = 0;
    sockFD = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

    if (sockFD == -1){
        printf("Fail to create a socket.");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in info;
    bzero(&info,sizeof(info));
    info.sin_family = PF_INET;
    info.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    info.sin_port = htons(8080);


    if(connect(sockFD,(struct sockaddr *)&info,sizeof(info)) == -1){
        perror("connect()");
    }


    char receiveMessage[100] = {};
    memset(receiveMessage, 0, sizeof(receiveMessage));

    char* input;
    while(scanf("%s", input) == 1){
        if(strcmp("exit", input) == 0){
            break;
        }

        if(send(sockFD, input, sizeof(input), 0) < 0){
            perror("send()");
        }

        if(recv(sockFD, receiveMessage, sizeof(receiveMessage), 0) < 0){
            perror("recv()");
        }

        printf("Server: %s\n",receiveMessage);
    }
    printf("close Socket\n");
    close(sockFD);
    return 0;
}
```

my server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main()
{
    int sockFD = 0, clientSockFD= 0;
    char inputBuffer[256] = {};
    //char outputBuffer[256] = {};
    fd_set masterFD;
    fd_set readFD;
    int fdMax;

    // create socket
    sockFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockFD == -1){
        perror("socket()");
        exit(0);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serverInfo, clientInfo;
    int addrLen = sizeof(clientInfo);
    bzero(&serverInfo, sizeof(serverInfo));

    serverInfo.sin_family = PF_INET;
    serverInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverInfo.sin_port = htons(8080);

    // bind port
    if(bind(sockFD, (struct sockaddr *)&serverInfo, sizeof(serverInfo))){
        perror("bind()");
    }
    // listen
    if(listen(sockFD, 10)){
        perror("listen()");
    }

    FD_SET(sockFD, &masterFD);
    fdMax = sockFD;

    while(1){
        readFD = masterFD;

        if(select(fdMax + 1, &readFD, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1){
            perror("select()");
            exit(0);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i <= fdMax; i++){
            if(FD_ISSET(i, &readFD)){
                if(i == sockFD){
                    if((clientSockFD = accept(sockFD, (struct sockaddr *)&clientInfo, &addrLen)) < 0){
                        perror("accept()");
                    }

                    FD_SET(clientSockFD, &masterFD);
                    if(clientSockFD > fdMax){
                        fdMax = clientSockFD;
                    }

                    printf("selectserver: new connection\n");
                }
                else{
                    int recvStatus = recv(i, inputBuffer, sizeof(inputBuffer), 0);
                    if(recvStatus <= 0){
                        if(recvStatus < 0){perror("recv()");}
                        else if(recvStatus = 0){printf("colse connected");}

                        close(i);
                        FD_CLR(i, &masterFD);
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("client: %s\n", inputBuffer);
                        send(i, inputBuffer, sizeof(inputBuffer), 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `send(i, inputBuffer, sizeof(inputBuffer), 0);` -->> `send(i, inputBuffer,recvStatus , 0);` (you were sending a buffer containing only a few characters, padded (upto size=256) with NULs, (or garbage))

Comment: It's work! Thanks @wildplasser ! But why use recvStatus to replace sizeof(inputBuffer)?

Comment: because `recv()`returns the number of characters it received. (or 0,or -1)

Comment: I see. Thanks your explanation！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 send(i, inputBuffer, sizeof(inputBuffer), 0);
```

Into:

```
 send(i, inputBuffer,recvStatus , 0);
```

The cause: you were sending a complete buffer, containing only a few intended characters, but padded (upto size=256) with NULs, (or whatever garbage is the buffer from previous calls))

`recv()` and `read()` return the number of characters received. (or 0 on EOF,or -1 on errors (some of which *could* be handled, for instance: EAGAIN, EINTR))